# How to measure and count sprint progress in new daily meeting approach?

Tags: scrum, burn-charts

I've recently found article on scrum alliance about new efficient form of Daily Scrum Meetings: [Change Your Daily Scrum Meeting](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918183151/https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2013/november/change-your-daily-scrum-meeting) which is based on a [2012 paper by Scott Downey and Jeff Sutherland](https://www.agilealliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ScrumMetricsAgile2012.pdf).

Basically we are changing standard questions during daily scrum meeting to following:

1. What did we achieve yesterday on  story 1?
2. What was our contribution in story 1? Estimate it in story points.
3. What is our plan for completing story 1 today?
4. What if anything is blocking you?

**My question is**: Who is estimating the progress? All team members or those who contributed in story? How to measure the progress in burn down and present to the team? Any tools, programs?

Comment: Please improve your question by making it less of an opinion poll. Specifically, did you read the [referenced paper](http://jeffsutherland.com/ScrumMetricsHICSS2013BWSubmissionFinal.pdf) from the article? If so, what have you actually tried, and why isn't that working for you?

Comment: Yes, please restate your question with how you think you are thinking of changing it, but more importantly, what are your goals or challenges are reason you are interesting in trying something different.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've precised the question.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't try to estimate partially completed story points

The recommended approach in Scrum is not to count partially completed stories. So, the answer to your question is no one needs to estimate the story point of incomplete stories.

However, one way to estimate remaining work is to create sub-tasks for stories. These tasks can be estimated in hours. The team members who are actually working on each task can estimate how many hours of work remain to complete that task. [Be honest about what effort you believe is required to complete each task regardless of how long has been spent to date and regardless of what was estimated in the first place.](http://www.allaboutagile.com/how-to-implement-scrum-in-10-easy-steps-step-8-track-progress-with-a-daily-burndown-chart/)

This will help the team to say something along the following lines:
"At the end of 5 days of a 10 day Sprint, our burn down chart shows that we have completed only 7 points out a total of 30 points committed for this Sprint. However, we have 2 hours left in the last task for completing a 8 point story." This approach will also have the benefit of shining the spotlight on that task and motivate the team to swarm on that story and take it to completion.

Comment: That's true in standard daily meeting aproach. But what about new form proposed by Jeff Sutherland in [here](http://jeffsutherland.com/ScrumMetricsHICSS2013BWSubmissionFinal.pdf)

Comment: That link is broken. The scrum metrics paper can be found at https://www.agilealliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ScrumMetricsAgile2012.pdf